# Bump out current user when same user login again in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, authentication, logic, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I am new to Laravel, so I don't know if this question is answered before or not. I have a requirement in my project which is explained below:

- User1 login to the system
- User1 login again from another system or browser
- The first logged in user should be logged out and allow the second logged in user into the system

I am using laravel 5.4 in my project with `passport authentication`. Is there any way to accomplish this?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally you'd do this by comparing the user's session ID to the session ID that they were assigned at login or refresh, generally by storing it in a database. I'm unfamiliar with Laravel, but it appears you can get the user's session ID like so `$session_id = Session::getId();`

Comment: Also, see this: [Laravel one session per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39938331/2084984)

Answer (score 0):

try to use database for session storage. In that way  it's much easier to achieve your goal

Comment: compare the user id not session id

Comment: We are using token authentication using Laravel passport

Comment: I may be wrong but isn't the idea of API authentication ignores user session? And authenticate each time of request? Thus you don't have to pump out the same user(token) because they don't have session.

Comment: Yes thats my point. Any idea how we can do this with token authentication?

Comment: No, since they don't have session, they don't actually stay in your system. So there's no need to log them out. when they request your api they essentially login to your system every single time.

Comment: Why would you do that may I ask? What's the reason?